# get the tab text on select jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I m using jquery ui tabs

I can get the index of the selected tab on "load" (ajax) event

```
$('#tabs').tabs(
      {
        load: function(e, ui) {
            if($('#tabs').tabs('option','selected') == 0) { }
      }
       });
```

Now i want to get the tab name

for eg...

```
<ul>
<li><a href="newprofile.jsp"><span>Profile</span></a></li>
<li><a href="ashout.jsp" id="friends"><span>Shouts</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to retrieve the text Profile when first tab is clicked 
or Shout when second tab is clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`ui` argument](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) passed in, specifically `ui.tab` to get the anchor element, like this:

```
var text = $(ui.tab).text();
```

I don't have your pages to load, [but you can test a demo here using the `select` event](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/tkVna/), it works the same way.